# Ruby script to print only the zip files

Tags: ruby

I want to find all zipfiles under a directory, and list their filenames (not the full path) to the customer, and copy the zip files under the current directory. Below is my script:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob('/ABC/DEF/GHI/XYZ/hello_world_1.2*.zip') do |z_file|
  if File.file?(z_file)
    puts "#{z_file.to_s}"
    FileUtils.cp_r(z_file, ".")
  end
end
```

Output:

```
/ABC/DEF/GHI/XYZ/hello_world_1.2.345.zip
/ABC/DEF/GHI/XYZ/hello_world_1.2.678.zip
```

My script lists the complete path, for example `/ABC/DEF/GHI/XYZ/hello_world_1.2.345.zip`. Need some direction on this. Any suggestion to improve it to print the zipfile names is appreciated.

Comment: You need to read [the File documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html). It has utility methods to do what you want. I'd recommend reading through all the documentation a few times. That way you'll know what's available; Even if you don't remember where it is you'll know there's something to start searching for. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/261593#261593

Answer (score 4):

You can use [File::basename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-basename) to get just the basename (xxx.zip) for your file.

Answer (score 0):

Working code is:

```
require 'fileutils'

Dir.glob('/ABC/DEF/GHI/XYZ/hello_world_1.2*.zip') do |z_file|
  if File.file?(z_file)
    puts File.basename("#{z_file.to_s}")
    FileUtils.cp_r(z_file, ".")
 end
end
```

Comment: It isn't necessary to provide your working code as an answer. Instead, select the answer that provided the information you needed to solve it.